# How to embed an admin class into another one, without relation between them?

Tags: symfony, symfony-sonata

I could not find any solutions, and don't even know if possible, but can I embed an admin class into another one, withoug having a relation attribute between the two entities? I need to put a separate block near an edit form, but it would be a separate edit form, no relation between them.
This is what i am trying: 
`$formMapper
       ->with('Article', array('class' => 'col-md-8'))
           ->add('title')
       ->end()
       ->with('Terms', array('class' => 'col-md-4'))
            ->add('anyName', 'sonata_type_admin',array(), array(
               'admin_code' => 'sonata.admin.term'
               ))
        ->end();`

But of course this gives me a "The current field `anyName` is not linked to an admin." exception. Maybe there is another way to include two separate admins in the same page, or can I make this solution work? I would appriciate a step-by-step solution:) Thx!